# jQuery adjusting iframe height

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, height

This code was passed to me. It makes my iframe set to 100% height of the screen:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){var height = $(window).height();
             $('iframe').css('height', height)
         });
```

I am new to javascript. How can I edit this code to make it set to 90% height rather than 100%? Also, this code targets all iframes, is there any way to make it target a specific iframe (by its ID or NAME value)? You can fiddle with this code here if you wish: http://jsfiddle.net/VurLy/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Multiply it by 90%?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var height = $(window).height();
    $('iframe').css('height', height * 0.9 | 0);
});
```

As for targeting by ID or name, just pass the appropriate selector to `$` instead of `'iframe'`.

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean with appropriate selector to $ instead of 'iframe'? Can you write a working example? Note that I am new to coding...

Comment: @HenrikPetterson: Pass the CSS selector that would apply to your element. For example, `$('#some-element')` would select the element with the `id` of `some-element`.

Comment: @HenrikPetterson Here is Jquery's documentation.  (note the complete css selector rules link also) http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: @HenrikPetterson, for selecting on the id: $('#scoop').  For selecting on the name: $('iframe[name="scoop"]').  Took the id and name from your jsFiddle.

Answer (score 2):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $('#YOUR_FRAME_ID_HERE').css('height', '90%')
});​
```

Comment: This did not work, I added the ID of the iframe but it did not do anything to the iframe.

Comment: I tried your example and it did not work, feel free to view it yourself: jsfiddle.net/VurLy/1

Comment: When I ran http://jsfiddle.net/VurLy/1/, and clicked the link, it loaded the iFrame at 90% of the height.  What doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

in jquery you can identify  which elemtents you want many different way  , most popular is by the id like this $('#scoop')  or by class , like this $('.scoop') - if the class was scoop

so that is how you identify the specific iFrame you want , then change the height like this

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   var height = $(window).height();
   $('#scoop').css('height', '90%'); 
});
```

Comment: I tried your example and it did not work, feel free to view it yourself: http://jsfiddle.net/VurLy/1/

Comment: you have the height set in the HTML " style= ... height="100%">  this will override any css

Comment: you can really just set it to 90% there and avoid jQuery is really more for dynamically changing the height , not just setting it on document.ready